# Changing the font name without changing the default font python

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I have tried to use `New Times New Roman` font instead of `Bitstream vera sans font` which is a default for `matplotlib` in the school network server.

I get the following error with `Times` or `Helvetica`, or `Arial`.

> not found error

To resolve this, I inquired to technical help to upload those fonts to server. I verified that they were uploaded.

Now after I removed `fontList.cache` and re-run the code as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x= np.arange(0,100)
y= 3*x-1
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlabel('x',fontdict={"name": "Times New Roman"})
plt.ylabel('y',fontdict={"name": "Times New Roman"})
plt.show()
```

The good thing is that I don't see the error message anymore, but bad thing is that after adding `fontdict={"name": "Times New Roman"},` the label has disappeared.

I can't find the reason of this without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you can just use:

```
    plt.xlabel('x', fontname = 'Times New Roman')
    plt.ylabel('y', fontname = 'Times New Roman')
```

I think that your error is coming from an incorrect use of fontdict.